# Count 2 columns on different conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, social-networking

I have this dataset:

```
id  uid    follows_uid  status      
1   1       2           ACTIVE
2   1       3           ACTIVE
3   3       1           ACTIVE
4   4       1           ACTIVE
5   2       1           ACTIVE
```

on giving `uid` I want to calculate how many users are following, and how many are followed by (the given user).

Result set will be:

```
following     followers
2             3
```

and here is the query which does the work:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as following, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_followers where follows_uid = 1  ) as followers
FROM user_followers
WHERE uid = 1 and `status` = 'ACTIVE'
```

Now the question is, In't there any other way to get this done? Or is it the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have separate indexes on `uid` and `follows_uid`, then I believe using subqueries as you did is the fastest way to retrieve the separate counts because each query will take advantage of an index to retrieve the count.

Comment: What is the difference in my query and this one? Please explain with optimization perspective

Comment: @Shaharyar sorry, didn't notice they're the same. I believe using subqueries as you have it is the fastest way to go if the proper columns are indexed because then each count can take advantage of an index then

Comment: Thanks, your comments are reasonable on all the answers. Now what would you say about @davmos answer? Is it more optimized than the actual query?

Comment: @Shaharyar unless you're using an older version of innodb, the subquery should run faster. but the only way to know for sure is to test. try both and let us know

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way of achieving it.

```
select following.*, followers.* from
(select count(uid) from user_followers where uid = 1) following,
(select count(follows_uid) from user_followers where follows_uid = 1) followers;
```

And, to answer your question, your subquery  approach is, in fact, the best way to achieve it. As pointed out by @FuzzyTree, you could use indexes to optimise your performance.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  IFNULL(SUM(IF(uid = 1, 1, 0)), 0) as following, 
  IFNULL(SUM(IF(follows_uid = 1, 1, 0)), 0) as followers
FROM user_followers
WHERE (uid = 1 OR follows_uid = 1) 
AND `status` = 'ACTIVE';
```

[Click here to see SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7aeb0/13)

Comment: @FuzzyTree . . . An aggregation query with no `group by` always returns one row, even if no rows match.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I stand corrected, however, in case a uid is not in the table, as the query is written it would return null, null as opposed to 0,0